DataFormatError whenever I filter a column
I have this Table on power query, power bi. All steps works well until the moment I filter the column "Company_Name" by "3M Company" (which exists in the column). With filter appplied I get this error: DataFormat.Error: Invalid cell value '#NAME?'.
The formula is:
Table.SelectRows(#"Tipo Alterado2", each Text.Contains([Company_Name], "3M"))

before that step, highlight the table, right click, remove errors. Does that step now work? If so the data has problems that is not immediately apparent before that step
